# Good joints for a feral cat house

Tags: joinery, plywood

I would like to build a few cat houses for local feral cats to help during the winter and protect them from coyotes.

I was thinking of using about 1 inch hardwood plywood. What are some good joints to use that provides the best chances for the cat house standing up against a coyote? The cat house will have two levels which the upper level allow the cat to remain safely from jaws of the coyote.

If there are any other suggestions I would love to hear those too.  Thanks.

Comment: Do not put up a sign that says "Cat House."

Comment: John, absolutely not.  I find that nicer things we put out for the feral cats tend to be taken or destroyed.  In this particular case these will be around my property so I will not need to worry about that.  Also, they need to hidden from the neighbors eyes.

Comment: Our small apartment building has a large rock mound covered with shrubbery filling the front yard. It is home to 2 very elusive feral cats. When I cycle quickly up to the front entry, I sometimes spot one or both of them before they dart into the bush.

Comment: Like with most things, there's never A best. There are good choices and often it doesn't make much/any difference which  you pick. Here, you could build this about a dozen different ways and there'd be no real difference in strength at the end of the day.

Answer (score 3):

You could use 2x2 (actually 1.5 inch square) as an integral frame to join each plywood piece at right angles. With 2.5 inch screws it would be a strong structure.
Keep the entry holes small, and always have a back door available for the little guys. At each entry you could build a "rattle-trap" that makes a noise when the cats approach each door. It would rattle when the coyote approaches, thus waking the cats. Back door exit, remember?

Comment: John, thanks for the suggestion of adding a second entry location to the house.  Thanks for the idea of using the 2x2.  I will definitely try to add those to the house.  In addition, I need to make sure cat house has some weight to it and fastened to the ground in some way.

Comment: Make the roof waterproof, draining away from the entrances. Add a piece of rigid foam to the floor, and slope it slightly toward the door. When the house is in position, pound a sharpened 2x2 into the ground at each corner (min 24") then screw the stakes to the structure.